# My python script doesn't work completely to send emails when a button is pressed

Tags: python, scripting

Howdy and good afternoon. I am pretty much a NOOB on with programming. I had a friend help me with a python script that when the button is pressed it will turn an led on and send an email message. When the button is pressed and held for more than 2 seconds and released it is supposed to turn the led of and send a separate email. The first "normal" email sends everytime even when the button is pressed and held, but the "Important" email doesn't send, however the led does turn off.
I am running Ubuntu Mate on a Raspberry PI 3
Here is part of the script.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
import datetime



body = "Email message"
sender = "Room 202 Help"
subject = "Room 202 Help Button"
to = ""
stmpAddress = "smtp.gmail.com"
username = ""
password = ""
normalBody = "Help needed in room 202"
importantBody = "Request Canceled Room 202"
ledPin = 23
buttonPin = 18
importantPress = 2 #seconds


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(buttonPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #makes the pin stay high another words it is set to about 3 volts
GPIO.setup(ledPin, GPIO.OUT) #makes the pin be an output

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = to
msg['Subject'] = subject
GPIO.output(ledPin,GPIO.LOW)

while True:
    buttonPress = GPIO.input(buttonPin)
    if buttonPress == False: #is the pin low?
        GPIO.output(ledPin,GPIO.HIGH)#turn on the led
        print('Button Pressed')#Yes it is low meaning it was shorted to ground
        buttonPressStart = datetime.datetime.now() #Time the button got pressed
        while GPIO.input(buttonPin) == False: # while it is still low
            time.sleep(0.1)#stay here till they let go of the button
        buttonPressEnd = datetime.datetime.now() # time the button was let go

        diff = buttonPressEnd - buttonPressStart#the differnce of when the button got pressed and let go, duration on button press

        if diff > datetime.timedelta(seconds = importantPress):
            msg.attach(MIMEText(importantBody, 'plain'))
            GPIO.output(ledPin,GPIO.LOW)#turn off the led if it's on
            print("Canceling")
        else:
            msg.attach(MIMEText(normalBody, 'plain'))

        server = smtplib.SMTP(stmpAddress, 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username, password)
        server.sendmail(username, to, msg.as_string())
        server.quit()#email sent



    time.sleep(0.01)#sleep a short time so to not eat all resources
```

Answer (score 1):

Going off an answer posted on [the Raspberry Pi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=126227&p=846026), you can see how long a button was pressed as such:

```
while True:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(PIN, GPIO.FALLING)
    print "Pressed"
    start = time.time()
    time.sleep(0.2)

    while GPIO.input(PIN) == GPIO.LOW:
        time.sleep(0.01)
    length = time.time() - start
    print length
```